# Custom JAXBContext for a Jersey service

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, glassfish, jersey

I'm writing a REST application using GlassFish 4 and Jersey. I have `@XmlNamedObjectGraph` in some entities, so I need to expose the same at a **few service end points** (may be in the same class) which is only possible by setting the `OBJECT_GRAPH` marshaller property. What's the way to do it? A custom `ContextResolver` will do it for all entities which I don't want.

Regarding named object graphs, http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/moxys-object-graphs-inputoutput-partial.html

Comment: So far I managed to create a custom MessageBodyWriter, and in my service end point, set an HTTP header which gets passed to the writer. The writer checks for the header and calls the property set method on JAXBContext to marshal.

Comment: Did you ever find a nice solution for this problem? I've been looking for one myself for many hours now. More generally, it seems to be nearly impossible to set custom, per-request properties on the `Marshaller`, which seems like a lacking feature to me.

Comment: @HeinBlöd I think I did, but I don't remember now. I scrapped the project later for something else.